# Unterschied zwischen Unfall und Vorfall

Tags: word-usage, difference, meaning, word-choice

Wo liegt der Unterschied zwischen einem *Unfall* und einem *Vorfall*? Ich habe versucht in verschidenen Wörterbüchern nachzuschlagen, aber ich habe nichts besonders unterschiedliches gefunden. Der *Unfall* scheint irgendwie negativer zu sein. Auf [de.Wiktionary.org](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Vorfall) ist *Vorfall* aber auch ein bischen negativ beschrieben:

> ein außergewöhnliches oder spezielles (und meist negatives) Ereignis / Geschehnis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ein Vorfall ist ein plötzlich eintretendes (für die Beteiligten ggf. unangenehmes) Ereignis.

Ein Unfall ist ein Vorfall, bei dem Menschen verletzt oder getötet werden oder Sachschaden entsteht.

Siehe dazu Duden: [Vorfall](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Vorfall) und [Unfall](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Unfall).

Ein Unfall ist also eine spezielle Form eines Vorfalles.

Comment: Es doll such Unfälle geben, die Leben vermehren ;)

Comment: Der Vollständigkeit halber: Nicht jeder "Vorfall, bei dem Menschen verletzt oder getötet werden oder Sachschaden entsteht", ist ein Unfall. Es könnte sich z.B. auch um ein Missgeschick, einen Überfall oder ein Attentat handeln.